# AdListener unimplement methods android

Tags: android, methods, admob

Since I couldn't find any documentation about this methods I couldn't find an answer.
What is the purpose of these methods?
I added this AdRequest as and my logcat went crazy. Is that wrong?

```
@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

}

@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

}   

@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}           
@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}  
@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the callback methods, using these methods you can check that what is the status of the ad.

For example if the ad is not recived, onFailedToReceiveAd() will be called.

Comment: So it's ok to add AdRequests in those methods?

Comment: No, Never do it. You need to load ad from some other method. It can be onCreate() or onResume() or any other way.

Comment: I see. Thanks. It was better to ask then do something to regret.

Comment: Ya exactly. Asking something is always better than asking nothing.